# How can I remove the text from the navigation bar back item

Tags: ios, swift

I'm trying to remove the text "Back" from the navigation back button, leaving just the back chevron, but everything I'm trying is not working. For example if I add something like the following, obtained from previous answers to the same question, to viewDidLoad:

```
 navigationItem.backBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(title: "go away", style: .plain, target: nil, action: nil)
```

or

```
navigationController?.navigationBar.backBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(title: "go away", style: .plain, target: nil, action: nil)
```

Then when the view appears it's still showing "< Back" in the navigation bar.

Here's what the views look like within captured within viewDidAppear.
Image:[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gv8Az.png)

Comment: In the previous viewController, set title = "" in `viewWillDisappear`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code snippet hope it will help you

**happy coding =)**

```
override func viewDidLoad() {

        DispatchQueue.main.async {

        if let navBar = self.navigationController?.navigationBar {
            navBar.backItem?.title = ""
           }
        }
    }
```

Comment: If works if its in the dispatch queue, but not if its not in a queue. Why does it need the queue to work?

Comment: queue execute after few seconds .. thats why it updated the backitem

Answer (score 0):

You should create a left button and set the action to return to the rootViewController.
In viewDidLoad:

```
let leftButton = UIBarButtonItem(title: "<", style: .plain, target: self, action: #selector(back(_ :)))
self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem  = leftButton
```

Comment: "<" does not looks like apple back image :/

Answer (score 0):

You are changing the wrong thing. You use this code here to change the title for the back button.

```
navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Back", style: .done, target: self, action: #selector(handleBack))
```

By doing this you need to add a selector for the button as well. Cause if you click the back button nothing will happen. This is how you would do that.

```
@objc private func handleBack() {
    navigationController?.popViewController(animated: true)
}
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, from Interface Builder, you can set previous UIViewController's Back Button on Navigation Item to " " (not empty string, space):

[image]